# render($page['content']) in the wrong place!

Tags: 7, theming

Ok I'm having this really weird problem with my Drupal 7 site. I have edited my `page.tpl.php` file. Following is the html where this oddity occurs

```
<table class="main_content">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="left_main">
            <div class="main_title">
                 <h2 class="centerBoxHeading"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

            </div>
            <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <div class="right_main">
                           <div class="main_title">
                                <h2 class="centerBoxHeading">Bestselling</h2>
                           </div>
                           <?php print render($page['right']['views_bestsellers-block']); ?>
                       </div>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td>
                   <div class="other_blocks_right">
                       <div class="main_title">
                           <h2 class="centerBoxHeading">Poll</h2>
                       </div>
                       <?php print render($page['right']['poll_blocks_11']); ?>
                   </div></td>
               </tr>
        </table>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So far everything looks fine. But when opened in the browser `print render($page['content']);` prints outside the table before it! I have checked this through firebug.

I have also edited a `node.tpl.php` file and everything is fine inside it.

Can anyone suggest what is going on?

Comment: `tables` and `div` elements have different styles. that might be the problem.. better you use `div` elements.

Comment: But using `table` is my requirement. Without it I can't seem to get my 'bestselling' and 'poll' blocks on the left. This is just weird, why wouldn't Drupal allow this?

Comment: why dont you override `CSS` on/with `table` and `div`

Comment: And if this is so, how come the other two blocks print inside the `table` while only this one doesn't?

Comment: In what way do I override the `CSS`?

Comment: Two ways: `Inline styling`, where you need to write the css in inline the element tags.

`Javascript` when page loads, change the css you want to display..

Its better to use `inline styling`, cos it renders before the page loads. and javascript will change the styling after page load..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3501/discussion-between-rafee-and-ali)

Comment: Thanks but I solved the problem. Turns out, the content in my `node.tpl.php` was wrapped in a `tr` tag. Don't know how it got there. When I removed it everything was fine. Thanks very much for your help anyway.. ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content in my `node.tpl.php` was wrapped in a `tr` tag. Don't know how it got there. When I removed it everything was fine.